# How can you subtract from a position in godot?

Tags: position, 2d, godot

I am pretty new to godot so I have a question about how you cant subtract from a position.
What I am trying to do is getting setting the global position of a object to the global position of my player but about 20 pixels in front.
So what I would like to do is:
`Object.global_position = global_position`
but then add 20 to the x of that global position.

Answer (score 2):

Short way: `Object.global_position = global_position + Vector2(20, 0)` (adding a vector directly to the position)

Long way:

```
var pos = global_position
pos.x += 20
Object.global_position = pos
```

(adding 20 to `x`)